# Change link-color, when slideshow image is last image, Jquery

Tags: jquery, slideshow, css-selectors

I have a slideshow with a few images.
There is a NEXT-Link (id: #next) to slide through.
I want to change the CSS-color of the NEXT-link, 
as soon as it arrives at last image.

I have something like that now:

```
if($('img.next()').is(":last-child")){$('#next').css('color:#666');}
else{$('#next').css('color:#111');}
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: It seems that you want to change the text colour of the link when there's still one more image left to show? And DOM traversal is dependant upon the HTML, without seeing your HTML we can't comment on how accurate it is, or suggest "what's wrong" with it.

Comment: BTW, Which Plugin are you using ?

Comment: You'll need to post the HTML and other JavaScript you're using.

Comment: Thanks guys for the efforts! At was just a matter of wrong syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.css()` syntax is a little off. If you are setting only one CSS property value pair, as you are in the code above, the `.css()` method takes two parameters.

If you need to add more than one property value pair to an element with `.css()` it accepts a single object as a parameter.

You can read more about it in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

For your specific case, the code should look more like this:

```
if($('img.next()').is(":last-child")){$('#next').css('color', '#666');}
else{$('#next').css('color', '#111');}
```

Hope that helps!